# MySQL export CSV without quotes

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I want to export the database to CSV file and read in MatLab.
I use phpMyAdmin to export to CSV file, but each field is with quotes, so that MatLab cannot correctly read it.
How can I export CSV file without quotes?

**update**

And how to use SQL command to export?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what version of phpMyAdmin you're using.  In 3.4.9 (the latest release as of today), You'd select `Export`, `Custom - display all possible options` radio button, Format `CSV`, and just erase the `Columns enclosed with:` field.

Comment: @xuc: phpMyAdmin (PMA) uses a script (found in your PMA's `libraries/export/` path) that builds the export; there isn't a simple SQL command to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is offtopic, but still: in PHPMyAdmin, if you use 'csv' as export, you can set the "Fields enclosed by" option to from `"` to nothing, right?